# How to use filter in Azure Cognitive Search when search term includes an &?

Tags: azure, odata, azure-cognitive-search

I have a 'name' field in a JSON document.  The index definition for the name field uses the standard.lucene analyzer.

One of the JSON documents has a 'name' field that looks something like, `'My Name & More'`

The following query from the Azure Search Explorer used from within the Azure portal fails:
With the error, Invalid expression: There is an unterminated string literal at position 17 in 'name eq 'My Name '. Parameter name: $filter" as shown in the image below.

**Failed query with filter**

[image]

This is fine.  & is a special character, so I try to escape it and have a query string like:
`$filter=name eq 'My Name %26 More'`. That string does not create an error, but does return an empty result set.

How do I construct a valid filter that matches the the actual name field and returns the correct document?

I tried to escape the filter string for the special character & and my query no longer errors, but the search result returns empty and not the expected document.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with expression **name eq 'My Name '&' More'** to get required results.

I have reproduced issue from my side and below are steps,

- Created search index in azure cognitive search.
- Initially tried with expression **$filter=content eq 'My Name & More'**. Got Invalid expression error same like you.
  [image]
- Tried with expression **content eq 'My Name '&' More'** and able to get results. I have two files having the word My Name '&' More and able to get those two files in search results.
  [image]
- In your case replace content with name in expression.